How can I start the ChatGpt app from an Android app?
How can I start the ChatGpt Android app from another Android app?
Option 1: First solution from ChatGpt does not work: launchIntent is always null.
Intent launchIntent = MainActivity.mainActivity.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.openai.chatgpt");
if (launchIntent != null) {
    startActivity(launchIntent);
} else {
    // always coming here ... logging an error
}

Option 2. When looking via Windows on my mobile, I don't see a folder with a name like chatgpt.
Option 3: This method only starts the Android app details information. Normally you can reach this page from Settings > Apps > ChatGpt.
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:com.openai.chatgpt"));
startActivity(intent);

So, the package name is ok.
Looking in my AndroidStudio folder, I could not find adb. I know that there are commands I might use.

For option 1, did you add a <queries> element to your manifest?

Please put this answer as a solution so I can mark it as the solution. Thank you!

Many methods on PackageManager, including getLaunchIntentForPackage(), require you to add a <queries> element to your manifest, advertising what apps you want to be able to see in the method result. This is for package visibility — you only can "see" the packages that you request via <queries>.
